# Elastic APM log correlation - find trace related to log entry

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I have an Elastic APM configured with Logging integration. I can successfully view a trace and identify the corresponding logs using the 'Logs' tab within APM.

I'm trying to achieve a reverse workflow where the user uses queries to identify a particular log entry (through Logs -> Stream) and is able to jump to the corresponding trace inside APM->Traces. I can do that manually by copying the trace id from the log entry and using it to filter out the trace inside APM, but I want to see if there's a way to make it more streamlined; an option like right-click -> View Trace.

Can this be achieved?